# Api version Modification

Tags: api, package, versioning

Can I upgrade or downgrade salesforce Api version?

I created a package from my org and tried to install on other org with different (lower)Api version, It gave me error

So i think i have to downgrade the api version of my org or upgrade the api version of other org.

I don't no how to do it and which one will be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can upgrade and downgrade the api version of any apex component from following screens.

- Edit Class and select version settings tab.

[image]

- Change the API version from following

[image]